# I keep on receiving different error messages while scraping with python-bs4 with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Every time I run the program I get a different attribute or error or the code runs perfectly fine.

I am scraping the price, reviews, title, and other attributes from Amazon.com. It was running fine with 1 URL, however, I embedded four into a list and wrote a for loop to scrape all of their attributes at once.

This is where I ran into some errors. So I took the list out of the for-loop and ran the scraping function manually through each part of the list. However, I am still getting what seem to be random errors and success after each time I run the program with no altercations.

Not sure what to do or how to fix this from here. Again I get a different error code every time.

'''

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_info(url):
    headers =  {"User-Agent" :'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
    review_score = soup.find(id='acrPopover').get_text()
    Quantity_of_Reviews = soup.find(id='acrCustomerReviewText').get_text()
    Shipping_Details = soup.find(id='price-shipping-message').get_text()
    price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()
    print(title.strip())
    Strippers = price.strip()
    print(Strippers[1:])
    print((review_score.strip()), (Quantity_of_Reviews.strip()), (Shipping_Details.strip()), )

url_list = ('https://www.amazon.com/CaiFang-Portable-Weather-Resistant-Outdoor/dp/B07WNHT769/ref=asc_df_B07WNHT769/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=385180969650&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14060933515508298001&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9007236&hvtargid=pla-844935074316&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=80078690298&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=385180969650&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14060933515508298001&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9007236&hvtargid=pla-844935074316',
            'https://www.amazon.com/Grand-Patio-Weather-Resistant-Outdoor/dp/B0854B7YNG/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=outdoor%2Bdeck%2Bend%2Btable&qid=1600363264&s=lawn-garden&sr=1-10&th=1',
            'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B085NBYH8Z/ref=sspa_dk_detail_3?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B085NBYH8Z&pd_rd_w=PiAk2&pf_rd_p=48d372c1-f7e1-4b8b-9d02-4bd86f5158c5&pd_rd_wg=X600j&pf_rd_r=ZH42TM2WV24C5RR7QSZS&pd_rd_r=377b69e1-b3e3-4255-8aa5-5f280bc01509&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzRjhYVFFLOUUyTFU4JmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjI3NzMzM1FISjdZUTFPQTJIRiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNDI0MDkxRDVPQlMzTlFRMUVJJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfZGV0YWlsJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==',
            'https://www.amazon.com/HollyHOME-Accent-Anti-Rust-Weatherproof-Outdoor/dp/B07Z8YLRN2/ref=pd_di_sccai_14?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07Z8YLRN2&pd_rd_r=9acf9b36-ef2b-4d69-a4af-1678af702d4c&pd_rd_w=hKpGb&pd_rd_wg=UMQZH&pf_rd_p=5415687b-2c9d-46da-88a4-bbcfe8e07f3c&pf_rd_r=F92DXW1YFXFEEX7C7F66&psc=1&refRID=F92DXW1YFXFEEX7C7F66')

get_info(url_list[1])
get_info(url_list[1])
get_info(url_list[2])
get_info(url_list[3])
```

'''
The errors are different. However.

Here it has ran successfully

'''

```
Grand Patio Steel Patio Side Table, Weather Resistant Outdoor Round End Table, Peacock Blue
39.99
4.7 out of 5 stars 123 ratings 
Grand Patio Steel Patio Side Table, Weather Resistant Outdoor Round End Table, Peacock Blue
39.99
4.7 out of 5 stars 123 ratings & FREE Shipping
CERBIOR Tray End Table, Round Metal Tray Table Side Sofa Table Anti-Rust and Waterproof Outdoor & Indoor Snack Table Accent Coffee Table Black
37.99
4.4 out of 5 stars 204 ratings & FREE Shipping. Details
HollyHOME Small Round Patio Metal Side Snack Table, Accent Anti-Rust Steel Coffee Table for Garden, Modern Weatherproof Outdoor End Table, (H) 17.55" x(D) 15.60", Navy Blue
39.99
4.6 out of 5 stars 357 ratings & FREE Shipping. Details
```

'''

Here it has run unsuccessfully.
'''

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/12678/OneDrive - Drexel University/CS171/CS172-Project#2-Amazon Price Grabber.py", line 22, in <module>
    get_info(url_list[1])
  File "C:/Users/12678/OneDrive - Drexel University/CS171/CS172-Project#2-Amazon Price Grabber.py", line 8, in get_info
    title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

'''
Another Unsuccessful attempt. Different Error and one of the functions went through.

'''

```
Grand Patio Steel Patio Side Table, Weather Resistant Outdoor Round End Table, Peacock Blue
39.99
4.7 out of 5 stars 123 ratings 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/12678/OneDrive - Drexel University/CS171/CS172-Project#2-Amazon Price Grabber.py", line 23, in <module>
    get_info(url_list[1])
  File "C:/Users/12678/OneDrive - Drexel University/CS171/CS172-Project#2-Amazon Price Grabber.py", line 8, in get_info
    title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

'''
And yet another different error code.

'''

```
Grand Patio Steel Patio Side Table, Weather Resistant Outdoor Round End Table, Peacock Blue
39.99
4.7 out of 5 stars 123 ratings & FREE Shipping
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/12678/OneDrive - Drexel University/CS171/CS172-Project#2-Amazon Price Grabber.py", line 24, in <module>
    get_info(url_list[2])
  File "C:/Users/12678/OneDrive - Drexel University/CS171/CS172-Project#2-Amazon Price Grabber.py", line 8, in get_info
    title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

'''

Comment: We'll need to know a little more about what errors you're seeing. For example, if they're related to elements not being found on the page, I'd be inclined to think that Amazon has designed their pages to thwart attempts at scraping.

Comment: @Kryten Just Edited:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `html5lib` as a parser instead of `html.parser`.

Install it with `pip install html5lib`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_info(url):
    headers =  {"User-Agent" :'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')
    title = soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text()
    review_score = soup.find(id='acrPopover').get_text()
    Quantity_of_Reviews = soup.find(id='acrCustomerReviewText').get_text()
    Shipping_Details = soup.find(id='price-shipping-message').get_text()
    price = soup.find(id='priceblock_ourprice').get_text()
    print(title.strip())
    Strippers = price.strip()
    print(Strippers[1:])
    print((review_score.strip()), (Quantity_of_Reviews.strip()), (Shipping_Details.strip()), )
    print('-' * 50)

url_list = ('https://www.amazon.com/CaiFang-Portable-Weather-Resistant-Outdoor/dp/B07WNHT769/ref=asc_df_B07WNHT769/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=385180969650&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14060933515508298001&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9007236&hvtargid=pla-844935074316&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=80078690298&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=385180969650&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14060933515508298001&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9007236&hvtargid=pla-844935074316',
            'https://www.amazon.com/Grand-Patio-Weather-Resistant-Outdoor/dp/B0854B7YNG/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=outdoor%2Bdeck%2Bend%2Btable&qid=1600363264&s=lawn-garden&sr=1-10&th=1',
            'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B085NBYH8Z/ref=sspa_dk_detail_3?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B085NBYH8Z&pd_rd_w=PiAk2&pf_rd_p=48d372c1-f7e1-4b8b-9d02-4bd86f5158c5&pd_rd_wg=X600j&pf_rd_r=ZH42TM2WV24C5RR7QSZS&pd_rd_r=377b69e1-b3e3-4255-8aa5-5f280bc01509&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzRjhYVFFLOUUyTFU4JmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjI3NzMzM1FISjdZUTFPQTJIRiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNDI0MDkxRDVPQlMzTlFRMUVJJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfZGV0YWlsJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==',
            'https://www.amazon.com/HollyHOME-Accent-Anti-Rust-Weatherproof-Outdoor/dp/B07Z8YLRN2/ref=pd_di_sccai_14?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07Z8YLRN2&pd_rd_r=9acf9b36-ef2b-4d69-a4af-1678af702d4c&pd_rd_w=hKpGb&pd_rd_wg=UMQZH&pf_rd_p=5415687b-2c9d-46da-88a4-bbcfe8e07f3c&pf_rd_r=F92DXW1YFXFEEX7C7F66&psc=1&refRID=F92DXW1YFXFEEX7C7F66')

get_info(url_list[1])
get_info(url_list[1])
get_info(url_list[2])
get_info(url_list[3])
```

Output:

```
Grand Patio Steel Patio Side Table, Weather Resistant Outdoor Round End Table, Peacock Blue
39.99
4.7 out of 5 stars 123 ratings & FREE Shipping
--------------------------------------------------
Grand Patio Steel Patio Side Table, Weather Resistant Outdoor Round End Table, Peacock Blue
39.99
4.7 out of 5 stars 123 ratings 
--------------------------------------------------
CERBIOR Tray End Table, Round Metal Tray Table Side Sofa Table Anti-Rust and Waterproof Outdoor & Indoor Snack Table Accent Coffee Table Black
37.99
4.4 out of 5 stars 204 ratings 
--------------------------------------------------
HollyHOME Small Round Patio Metal Side Snack Table, Accent Anti-Rust Steel Coffee Table for Garden, Modern Weatherproof Outdoor End Table, (H) 17.55" x(D) 15.60", Navy Blue
39.99
4.6 out of 5 stars 357 ratings & FREE Shipping. Details
--------------------------------------------------
```